# Unable to populate UITableView from NSMutable array from another view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

I have 2 VCs, first is `BooksDetailViewController` which has the NSString `myBookString`. Another on is `FavBooksViewController` which has the `favBookList` NSMutableArray. I want to pass the NSString `myBookString` from the 1st VC to include it in the `favBookList` NSMutableArray which then populates the table.

I have included `@class FavBooksViewController;` in the `BooksDetailViewController.h`

Imported `#import "FavBooksViewController.h"` in the `BooksDetailViewController.m`

The action in the `BooksDetailViewController.m` looks like this:

```
- (IBAction)addToFav:(id)sender {
    FavBooksViewController *mdvc;
    [mdvc.self.favBookList addObject:myBookString];
}
```

In `FavBooksViewController.h` I have

```
@interface FavBooksViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) id delegate;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *favBookList;
```

In the `FavBooksViewController.m` - `#import "FavBooksDetailViewController.h"`
In the ViewDidLoad I tried to include this line

```
self.favBookList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:nil];
```

But I have commented it out. With it our without it the UITableView isn't working.
And of course I have this:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.favBookList count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
           UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView 
                                 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"favBooksCell"];

        cell.textLabel.text = [self.favBookList
                               objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        return cell;
}
```

No matter what, the UITableView is just empty, no cells, nothing.
What can be the possible mistake here? What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure the object is added to the NSMutableArray?

Comment: Hey SergiusGee, just to be sure. have you linked your tableView with the delegate/datasource? It happens to me sometimes :-)

Comment: @iGranDav Yeah, I sure have :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of adding the string to the array in the **BooksDetailViewController** , just pass the string to the **FavBooksViewController** and then add it to the array in your FavBooksViewController.

```
- (IBAction)addToFav:(id)sender {
    FavBooksViewController *mdvc;
    [mdvc setFavBook:myBookString];  
    //favBook is a NSString member object in your FavBooksViewController class

     [self.navigationController pushViewController:mdvc animated:YES];
}
```

Just try if this works.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to initiates the cell in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

The code should be :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
        static NSString *identifier = @"favBooksCell";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView 
                                 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
        if(!cell) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier];
        }

        cell.textLabel.text = [self.favBookList
                               objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        return cell;
}
```

Try this ;-)

Hope this helps.

Comment: You have to do this, but it seems that your array is still empty. Try to remove self in your addToFav method. You now should have [mdvc.favBookList addObject:myBookString];

Comment: It's the first thing I asked. Are you sure the object is added to the NSMutableArray?